# django flatpages and redirects app - case-sensitivity

Tags: python, django

Flatpages and redirect apps are awesome. Ready-to-use fun things...
But, they are case-sensitive in URL. How can I make it case-insensitive?

I mean, I gave in admin page (redirects app) the old and new paths.

```
/oldpath/
```

and

```
/newpath/
```

but if I give `/Oldpath/`, i get a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `urls.py` based on the [flatpages `urls.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/flatpages/urls.py) and make the regex case insentive by using `?(i)`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.flatpages import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?i)(?P<url>.*)$', views.flatpage, name='django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage'),
]
```

and include it in your root `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Comment: wow, fantastic! thanks dude, finally learnt something new today

Comment: should the ``url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),`` at the end of root urls.py?